# PostgreSQL: Allow only one instance of stored procedure to run at a time

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure on Postgres, which processes large data and takes a good time to complete.
In my application, there is a chance that 2 processes or schedulers can run this procedure at same time. I want to know if there is a built in mechanism in db to allow only instance of this procedure to run at db level.

I searched the internet, but didn't find anything concrete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built in to define a procedure (or function) so that concurrent execution is prevented.

But you can use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) to achieve something like that.

At the very beginning of the procedure, you can add something like:

```
perform pg_advisory_lock(987654321);
```

which will then wait to get the lock. If a second session invokes the procedure it will have to wait.

Make sure you *release* the lock at the end of the procedure using `pg_advisory_unlock()` as they are not released when the transaction is committed.

If you use advisory locks elsewhere, make sure you use a key that can't be used in other places.